# In how many ways 15 people be chosen for 4 distinct positions

Tags: combinatorics

There are 15 people and 4 positions (north, south, east, and west)

How can I evaluate how many possible arrangements of people can be done where position matters? Having only one person per a position at a time.

Comment: Are we placing just $4$ people in these "chairs," one person to a chair? Then the South chair can be filled in $15$ ways, and for each choice the East chair can be filled in $14$ ways, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

$\binom{15}{4}$ - it's called a binomial coefficient, and it's the number of combinations C(15,4).

Comment: this gives number of ways of picking $4$ people; this should be multiplied by the number of permutations since each position is distinct, the final answer should be $$\binom{15}{4}\times 4! =   15\times 14\times 13\times 12$$

Comment: True, I should've read the question more carefully :)

Answer (score 1):

You can first to chose the four who will be positioned. You can do this in $\binom{15}{4}$ different ways.

Now, for each group of four people you can organize them in $4!$ different ways. So, the answer is

$$ 4!\binom{15}{4} $$